# login to a SharePoint Site using HTML Link thorugh passing the credential

Tags: c#, sharepoint, navigation, credentials

I'm currently in the implementation phase of a project (*two parts*) that works as an `aggregator` for datasources form two sources (`database tables` and `sharepoint lists, libraries..`).
 admin user can generate the report and manage datasources, then a web module going to display the selected datasources for specific report (of course there are relations between the selected datasources.. etc)

final output must often like this:

[image]

[image]

if you noticed the `Click here` link which must navigate the end-user to the source sharepoint item in the sharepoint website, now the problem is whenever a user clicked this link it prompts a credential window in order to proceed with the navigation
 i want to get red of this issue and I know i cant do much with `html link` so any suggestions? im open to new ideas

Thank you in advance

Comment: what type of auth is it? windows or forms? is it on an intranet?

Comment: @djeeg: links to sharepoint website, so it would be windows authentication, and its in an intranet environment

Answer (score 0):

What site is these reports displayed on ? ASP.NET or SharePoint ?

The best would be to put this report site under the `_layouts` directory of sharepoint so that user is automatically authenticated when they access this site. When the user further clicks the link, since he is already authenticated, he won't be prompted for credentials.

Comment: sorry for not being clear, the reports i already mentioned is named by us "reports" but they have nothing to do with sharepoint reports nor asp.net reports (if there are any)the report (in our terms) displayed over an asp.net module.

Comment: So, what are they ? Where are they hosted ?

Comment: Report: set of datasources (tables and sharepoint list/libraries) selected by the admin(regardless the way admin picks the datasources) and `inner joined` with each other to be displayed as blocks `Grid Controls` in the asp.net module (hosted in DNN solution), the asp.net module reads report's datasources from the database and according to their joins and credential the module will connect to those datasource and fetch the data to be finaly available to end-user as shown in the attached img.. is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, so you can put this asp.net web application under _layouts in sharepoint .. isn't it ? And then access it http://<server>/_layouts/Report.aspx , now since you are already authenticated to sharepoint, clicking the link won't result in further authentication